# Constructor Injection pattern using C# and Autofac

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, repository-pattern

I am a bit new to DI pattern and having some problems in hand.
The whole story goes like this:

- There is a console app called 'DataGenerator' responsible to generate
  sample data for the entire app. A reference to 'Autofac' has been added to this project. Here is the code snippet for creating a list of country:

[image]

The exception raising up in the above foreach loop says:

> {"None of the constructors found with 'Autofac.Core.Activators.Reflection.DefaultConstructorFinder' 
>           on type 
>       'TechnicalTest.Service.AppServices.CountryService' can be invoked with the available services and parameters:\r\nCannot resolve parameter 
>       'TechnicalTest.Repository.EntityRepositories.ICountryRepository countryRepository' of constructor 'Void 
>       .ctor(TechnicalTest.Repository.EntityRepositories.ICountryRepository, TechnicalTest.Repository.UnitOfWork.IUnitOfWork)'."}

- There is another project including the app services. Here is one of which:

[image]

Please note that a GenericRepository and UnitOfWork project has been added to introduce every entity repository. For example:
[image]

I have search through the web for the exception and how I could get ride of it but unfortunately could not figure out a solution for my case. I guess there must be something wrong with the CountryService constructor or something like that. 
Any helps or ideas would be kindly appreciated.

Comment: Have you registered `DbContext` with your container? From the error message it looks like the problem is with resolving the dependencies for `CountryRepository` that is the problem.

Comment: @JackHughes: am sorry the code of the main class I have posted missed a line of code `builder.RegisterType<CountryService>().As<ICountryService>();`. Isn't it enough to use the service or `DbContext` should be registered too?

Comment: All dependencies for classes registered in the container must be registered with the container. How can the container create an instance of `CountryRepository` without all of the dependencies it requires?

Comment: ..well it seems you're right... I should do that and see what happens

Comment: @JackHughes: Thanks a million.. now it works fine and am so happy with that.. Just one more question: to register the `DbContext` I've made a reference to my `Model` project in which `DbContext` and `DbSet<T>` have been written. Do you think this referencing would be fine in terms of design and architecture? I guess it sounds not bad as I don't know any other course of action..

Comment: By the way you can make an answer and I vote you up :)

Comment: Referencing your model project isn't a problem in itself though that depends on the size of the project. If you have some massive project with millions of lines then maybe it would be a problem. On a small project of a few tens of thousands of lines I doubt it would be a problem. One way to clean up registering your container is to use a `Module`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you registered `DbContext` with your container? From the error message it looks like the problem is with resolving the dependencies for `CountryRepository`.

All dependencies for classes registered in the container must be registered with the container. How can the container create an instance of `CountryRepository` without all of the dependencies it requires?